# JW player close video in full screen

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jwplayer

I'm using JW player and i can watch video in full screen, but when i'm clicking 'ESC' button then window is closed. Need to exit from full screen into small previous screen and video should work further, but it closed anyway. This issue is only in IE browser. Do you have any solutions how to fix that?

Comment: which version of IE ?

Comment: here is small POC in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/6YyXH/108/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the JW Player API in this fashion to make it whatever size you want at any point:

```
jwplayer('yourPlayerDivId').resize(width, height);
```

Resizes the player to the specified width and height, in pixels. It's also possible to set percentages (e.g. 50%).